# How to solve an attribute error when using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, findall

I am reading in a .html file that looks similar to the following format:

```
html = '''
<tr>
<td class="SmallFormText" colspan="3">hours per response:</td><td class="SmallFormTextR">23.8</td>
</tr>
<hr>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" summary="Form 13F-NT Header Information">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="FormTextC">COLUMN 1</td><td class="FormTextC">COLUMN 2</td><td class="FormTextC">COLUMN 3</td><td class="FormTextR">COLUMN 4</td><td class="FormTextC" colspan="3">COLUMN 5</td><td class="FormTextC">COLUMN 6</td><td class="FormTextR">COLUMN 7</td><td class="FormTextC" colspan="3">COLUMN 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FormText"></td><td class="FormText"></td><td class="FormText"></td><td class="FormTextR">VALUE</td><td class="FormTextR">SHRS OR</td><td class="FormText">SH/</td><td class="FormText">PUT/</td><td class="FormText">INVESTMENT</td><td class="FormTextR">OTHER</td><td class="FormTextC" colspan="3">VOTING AUTHORITY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FormText">NAME OF ISSUER</td><td class="FormText">TITLE OF CLASS</td><td class="FormText">CUSIP</td><td class="FormTextR">(x$1000)</td><td class="FormTextR">PRN AMT</td><td class="FormText">PRN</td><td class="FormText">CALL</td><td class="FormText">DISCRETION</td><td class="FormTextR">MANAGER</td><td class="FormTextR">SOLE</td><td class="FormTextR">SHARED</td><td class="FormTextR">NONE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FormData">1ST SOURCE CORP</td><td class="FormData">COM</td><td class="FormData">336901103</td><td class="FormDataR">8</td><td class="FormDataR">335</td><td class="FormData">SH</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="FormData">SOLE</td><td class="FormData">7</td><td class="FormDataR">335</td><td class="FormDataR">0</td><td class="FormDataR">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FormData">1ST UNITED BANCORP INC FLA</td><td class="FormData">COM</td><td class="FormData">33740N105</td><td class="FormDataR">7</td><td class="FormDataR">989</td><td class="FormData">SH</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="FormData">SOLE</td><td class="FormData">7</td><td class="FormDataR">989</td><td class="FormDataR">0</td><td class="FormDataR">0</td>
</tr>    '''
```

In this code, I am trying to extract the information between the < tr > and < /tr > tags. In particular, I want to assign a given information, such as "NAME OF ISSUER" to a column name called "NAME_OF_ISSUER", using beautiful soup. However, when I run the following code, I am facing an error that looks simple to be solved (it's more or less a data formatting issue). Given that I am new to Python, I got stuck for a few hours trying alternative solutions. I would appreciate any comments or feedback.

Here is my code (please run the above code as well to obtain the html data):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')[11:]
positions = []
dic = {}
position = rows.find_all('td')
dic["NAME_OF_ISSUER"] = position[0].text
dic["CUSIP"] = position[2].text
dic["VALUE"] = int(position[3].text.replace(',', ''))*1000
dic["SHARES"] = int(position[4].text.replace(',', ''))
positions.append(dic)
df = pd.DataFrame(positions)
```

I am getting an "AttributeError" right after defining position, stating that the list object has no attribute "find_all".

What exactly does this mean? Also, how would I need to transform the html data to avoid this issue?

Edited part:

Here is the full stack trace:

```
position = rows.find_all('td')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-37353b5ab2ef>", line 1, in <module>
    position = rows.find_all('td')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? It shows us the line and likely what attribute is the problem.

Comment: `soup.find_all` gives you a python `list` of elements. Lists don't have a `find_all` method. You likely want a `for` loop to go through those elements and do a `find_all` on them.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply, @tdelaney. I have posted the trace below the edited part. 

I see, but even when I was looping over the rows, I was still getting the same error. I will give your code a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`soup.find_all` returns a python `list` of elements. All you need to do is iterate through the list and grab data from those elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

# scan for header row and trim list
for index, row in enumerate(rows):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells and "NAME OF ISSUER" in cells[0].text.upper():
        del rows[:index+1]
        break

# convert remaining html rows to dict to create dataframe
positions = []
for position in rows:
    dic = {}
    cells = position.find_all('td')
    dic["NAME_OF_ISSUER"] = cells[0].text
    dic["CUSIP"] = cells[2].text
    dic["VALUE"] = int(cells[3].text.replace(',', ''))*1000
    dic["SHARES"] = int(celss[4].text.replace(',', ''))
    positions.append(dic)
df = pd.DataFrame(positions)
```

Comment: I just tried running this code with the posted sample (i.e., the sample html file), but the df variable seems to be empty, @tdelaney. In other words, the size of the DataFram is (0,0). Is this possibly due to the data formatting error? In other words, when I am saving the original XML file (which comes from the SEC 13-F filings webpage) as a HTML file, could this cause potentially the reason why the df variable is empty? By just looking manually into the html variable (that is provided in the original post), there are many 'tr' statements. So I am unsure why the df variable is empty.

Comment: I had a bug. I was interating through the empty positions list instead of the rows. I also updated to scan for the header row instead of just assuming it was at index 10.

Comment: thank so much for your helpful comments. I greatly appreciate your time and support!